# How to specify null value as filter in a Doctrine query?

Tags: php, null, doctrine, dql

I am using Doctrine 1.1 in Zend. I am trying to write a query that will return records that have a null value in a certain column.

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('a.*')
    ->from('RuleSet a')
    ->where('a.vertical_id = ?', null);

    $ruleset_names_result = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I have three records in the ruleset table which have a *NULL* value in the vertical_id column yet the query doest not find these.

Appreciate the help.

Sid.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

I use doctrine with symfony, and this is how I do:

`where('a.vertical_id is NULL');`

Comment: incredible... you had to have caps on the NULL, took me an hour to find the error... thanks. should have googled stackoverflow first.

Comment: By the was the opposite would be `where('a.vertical_id is not NULL');`

Answer (score 21):

If you are using Symfony 2 and above, you can use this code:

```
->where($qb->expr()->isNull('a.vertical_id'));
```

Reference:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

Comment: Your answer references to version 2 of doctrine. The question concerns version 1...